# PyWin32 excluding one specific instance of tag on all emails read in from PST

Tags: python, html, outlook, pywin32, pst

I've been developing a Python tool to ingest and write all emails from a PST exported from Outlook to individual .html files. The issue is that when opening the PST in outlook and checking the source information for emails individually, it includes this specific line:

`<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

which IS NOT being included when importing the PST with Pywin32 and reading all the emails in the PST. To see what it looks like in a chunk -

From Outlook: `<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">`

What is exported from the tool: `<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">`

The contents of the emails are otherwise ENTIRELY identical except for that one tag.

My code:

```
htmlEmails = 0
encryptedEmails = 0
totalEmails = 0
richPlainEmails = 0
filenameCount = 1
mycounter2 = 1

#Adjusting name of PST location to be readable
selectedPST = str(selectedPST.replace('/', '\\'))
print('\nRunning:' , selectedPST)
outlook.AddStore(selectedPST)
PSTFolderObj = find_pst_folder(outlook, selectedPST)

def find_pst_folder(OutlookObj, pst_filepath):
    for Store in OutlookObj.Stores:
        if Store.IsDataFileStore  and Store.FilePath == pst_filepath:
            return Store.GetRootFolder()
    return None

def enumerate_folders(FolderObj):
    for ChildFolder in FolderObj.Folders:
        enumerate_folders(ChildFolder)
    iterate_messages(FolderObj)

def iterate_messages(FolderObj):
    global mycounter2
    global encryptedEmails
    global richPlainEmails
    global totalEmails
    global htmlEmails

    for item in FolderObj.Items:
        totalEmails += 1
        try:
            try:
                body_content = item.HTMLbody
                mysubject = item.Subject
                writeToFile(body_content, exportPath, mysubject)
                mycounter2 = mycounter2 + 1
                htmlEmails += 1
            except AttributeError:
                #print('Non HTML formatted email, passing')
                richPlainEmails += 1
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            encryptedEmails += 1
            pass

def writeToFile(messageHTML, path, mysubject):
    global mycounter2
    filename = '\htmloutput' + str(mycounter2) + '.html'

    #Check if email is rich or plain text first (only HTML emails are desired)
    if '<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->' in messageHTML or '<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->' in messageHTML:
        raise AttributeError()

    else:
        file = open(path + filename, "x", encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            messageHTML = regex.sub('\r\n', '\n', messageHTML)
            file.write(messageHTML)
            
        #Handle any potential unexpected Unicode error
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception: ' , e)
            try:
                #Prints email subject to more easily find the offending email
                print('Subject: ', mysubject)
                print(mycounter2)
                file.write(messageHTML)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Tried utf decode: ', e)
  
        file.close()
```

Because the emails otherwise are identical, I can only assume this is being done by the library. I'm wondering if there's a reason that meta tag is excluded, or if its a bug in PyWin32?

Answer (score 0):

After much exploration and discussion with people familiar with PyWin32 and having my code reviewed and tested, it seems Outlook is the bad actor here.

I discovered that Outlook was causing the exact same behavior when attaching an email to another email. That is, if I sent an email, I could check the source info and it contained the  information. When I then attached it to another email, the file would have the  tag stripped.

As a result, I switched to LibPFF ( https://pypi.org/project/libpff-python/ ) to circumvent this. It allows PST's to be read in as well as parse through the HTML of emails within the PST.

The code for LibPFF looks like this: (just include the path to the PST in the path+pstname spot):

```
import pypff
pst_file = pypff.file()
pst_file.open(path+pstname)

root = pst_file.get_root_folder()

for folder in root.sub_folders:
    for sub in folder.sub_folders:
        for message in sub.sub_messages:
            body_content =  message.get_html_body()
            print(str(body_content))
```

This is essentially a work around, but can provide the same results depending on the use case. As for why Outlook does this, I can only assume that the  tag with the charset info is required for sending the email over their server, so when it's attached to another email, it's seen as useless and is stripped.